# How to design void method junit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

```
public class ParmsData {

    @Autowired
    private ParamsCache paramsCache;

    private Map<String, List<String>> beanData = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());

    public void init(){
        this.beanData = Collections.synchronizedMap(paramsCache.allParams().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(FxParams:: getSysPara, param -> Arrays.stream(param.getSysParaValue().split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList()))));
    }
}
```

1. How to design init() method junit test?
2. Please give me the exmple code thanks.

Comment: Well, you do this by: picking up a book about unit testing and starting to read. Then you start playing around with smaller examples, ideally code that doesn't rely on such complex frameworks as spring. And then, when you understand the basics why and how to write proper unit tests, then you pick up a tutorial that guides you on writing unit tests in the context of spring. You see, you learn programming by researching and TRYING things yourself. Not by dropping your code (home)work assignment onto other people asking them to do the work for you.

Comment: you test void methods by testing the non-void methods that use it

Comment: in your case, you can have your test first execute your init, and then test the result of a getter